# Columns and rows in cassandra datastax opscenter

Tags: windows, cassandra, opscenter, nosql

I have just started learning cassandra. I am using datastax opscenter.

I am able to create columnfamily, but could not able to find to add the columns and rows in columnfamily through opscenter, though I am able to do on cqlsh.

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsCenter does not have the ability to add columns and rows into Cassandra. The data explorer feature is actually soon to be deprecated. You can, however, use DevCenter: http://www.datastax.com/download-ops-dev#DataStax_DevCenter to create and alter data models.

As for loading data in, you can certainly do simple inserts through CQLSH within Cassandra as well as DevCenter but to do any meaningful data loading, you'll want to take a look at one of the drivers or loaders:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your attentions, but could i know is there any program for cassandra which can be use like we use management studio for sql server

Comment: DataStax DevCenter is the closest thing to management studio: http://www.datastax.com/download-ops-dev#DataStax_DevCenter

Cassandra is still relatively new so it'll take a bit of time for it get all the cool toys some of the older RBMS's have but I assure you it's coming :) The community is strong and constantly evolving and creating cool tools.